# Nicehash autoselected algorithm with very high difficulty

Tags: algorithms

I'm new at this so please bare with me

I have a couple gtx 750 lying around so I decided to give mining a try.

I used nicehash, according to the site "NiceHash Miner autoselects the most profitable algorithm for your GPU/CPU".

Nicehash autoselected **Cryptonight** for me. With 80,000 Diff

While observing the result, I noticed I get ***"yes!" / "yay!"*** only every after 5-10.

I tried to used other algorithms such as NeoScrypt and it gives ***"yes!" / "yay!"*** every 2 mins.

BTW neoscrypt only has 32-64 diff

So my question is which algorithm should I try?

Answer (score 1):

Difficulty isn't the only factor in choosing which coin is most profitable. NiceHash may have selected Cryptonight because although you will mine fewer blocks, each block is worth more, so you will make more overall.